# Regardind a Java sandbox

Tags: java, file-permissions, sandbox

I have a stack of .java files that are submissions from a programming contest. I want to run said files (in a sandbox) and I expect them to accept input from a text file (provided by me) and also save output to text file.

What permissions should I be using to make sure the untrusted .java files can **ONLY** output text file to desired file location?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running it in unix, then you can create a user that only has permissions to output in that folder.  As long as you aren't running it with admin rights it should be pretty easy.

Comment: I know how to do that. But I was wondering if I could restrict the type of files (.txt) it can write to my machine because I don't want it to be able to create anything else.